# Minecraft game play is red & blue, but title is gray

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Everything in *Minecraft* is red & blue and makes it hard to see.  It's like one of those red & blue 3D movies. How do I change it back to normal?

Answer (score 24):

Check that you haven't turned on the 3D Anaglyph option (yes Minecraft does have one) by accident under options > Video Settings.